# How to create Lists dynamically in sencha and add them to navigation view?

Tags: web-services, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

How to create Lists dynamically in sencha and add them to navigation view? I am making a webservice call to get the list of folders. When i click on any folder it should show the subfolders present in a list. Subfolders may or may not folders inside them. How to create a list when there is subfolder? I want to navigate back so i have to add all these to a navigationn view. Please let me see a piece of code explaining how to do that.

Comment: Please, show list code of sencha. Maybe can I help you.

Comment: You should use "NestedList" instead of "List+NavigationView".

Comment: And please add the code where you create the Navigation list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create store instances:

```
  var instanceStore = Ext.create(
            'Project.store.MyListStore');
        store.each(function (record) {
            instanceStore.add(record);
        });
```

Create a list dynamically:

```
  var ListDetails = Ext.create(
                    'Project.view.NavigationList', {

                        items:[

                        ],
                        itemTpl:new Ext.XTemplate(workItemListTpl),
                        store:instanceStore
                    });
```

Create a navigation view panel and push the list into the view:

```
 var panelId = Ext.getCmp('NavigationViewPanel');
 panelId.push(ListDetails );
```

This method worked for me to create lists and add them dynamically to the same navigation view.

Answer (score 0):

To my experience:

- Easiest way: just use **Ext.NestedList**. There are a couple of things to care about if you use this component. Let's first see the documentation:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.NestedList

and a very good example:

http://sencha-nested-list.heroku.com/

- Recommended way: use several **Ext.List**. I mean you create your list of "outermost" folders first, then catch event on `listitemtap` and render appropriate lists showing subfolders.

Comment: {
                xtype:'list',
                id:'workitemlistdetails',
                
                style:{
                    'border-right':'0.01px  black',
                    'color':'green'
                },
                onItemDisclosure:function () {

                },

                itemTpl:'{data}'
            }
This list is getting populated on web service call. How to create one more list on item disclosure. To use nested list i will not be knowing how many subfolders will be there inside a subfolder

Comment: Nested list we can create only when we know the number of nests present inside a list